# Apache Spark: SparkFiles.get(fileName.txt) - Unable to retrieve the file contents from SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark

I used `SparkContext.addFile("hdfs://host:54310/spark/fileName.txt")` and added a file to `SparkContext`. I verified its presence using `org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(fileName.txt)`.  It showed an absolute path, something like `/tmp/spark-xxxx/userFiles-xxxx/fileName.txt`.

> Now I want to **read that file from the above given absolute path
>   location from `SparkContext`**.  I tried 
>   `sc.textFile(org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("fileName.txt")).collect().foreach(println)`
>   It considers the path returned by `SparkFiles.get()` as a ***HDFS
>   path***, which is incorrect.

I searched extensively to find any helpful reads on this, but ran out of luck.

*Is there anything wrong in the approach?* Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the code and the outcome:

```
scala> sc.addFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/spark/fileName.txt")

scala> org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("fileName.txt")
res23: String = /tmp/spark-3646b5fe-0a67-4a16-bd25-015cc73533cd/userFiles-a7d54640-fab2-4dfa-a94f-7de6f74a0764/fileName.txt

scala> sc.textFile(org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("fileName.txt")).collect().foreach(println)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/spark-3646b5fe-0a67-4a16-bd25-015cc73533cd/userFiles-a7d54640-fab2-4dfa-a94f-7de6f74a0764/fileName.txt
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Can you add code sample and error logs here

Comment: @vaquarkhan Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to local file using the "file://" syntax.

```
sc.textFile("file://" + org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("fileName.txt"))
.collect()
.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how is that file related to local file system?  I added the file to SparkContext.

Comment: When you add a file using sparkContext spark sends the file to driver and workers. SparkFiles.get call gets you the absolute path of the file which is local to the worker or driver it's not uploaded to hdfs.