# Spark submit --files not working to copy truststore file to worker nodes in google dataproc

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to submit a spark job using 'gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark'. To connect to ES cluster I need to pass the truststore path.

The job is successful if I copy the truststore file to all the worker nodes and give the absolute path as below:

```
esSparkConf.put("es.net.ssl.truststore.location","file:///tmp/trust.jks");
```

But I don't want to do like this. If the worker nodes are more copying to each node is difficult.
I tried to pass the truststore file using --files option like below:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster=sprk-prd1  --region=<> --files=trust.jks --class=ESDumpJob --jars=gs://randome/jars/ESDump-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

code snipped in ESDumpJob:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("My ES job");
sparkConf.set("spark.es.nodes.wan.only","true")
.set("spark.es.nodes", <es_nodes>)
                    .set("spark.es.net.ssl","true")
                    .set("spark.es.net.ssl.truststore.location","trust.jks"))
                    .set("spark.es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", "pass"))
                    .set("spark.es.net.http.auth.user","test")
                    .set("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "test"));

sparkSession = SparkSession
                    .builder().master("local")
                    .config(sparkConf)
                    .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
                    .getOrCreate();

JavaRDD<MyData> data = //create rdd
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(data, "my_index", ImmutableMap.of("es.mapping.id", "id"));
```

I am getting below error in this case

```
17:15:42 Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at [trust.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI.
17:15:42    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(SSLSocketFactory.java:195)
17:15:42    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadTrustManagers(SSLSocketFactory.java:226)
17:15:42    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:173)
```

Comment: `make sure it is available on the classpath` - Did you try setting the executor classpath? Or `a valid URI` - Did you try `file://trust..jks`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer How to set executors class path? As I said I don't want to copy the file to all the worker nodes.

The job is successful if I copy the truststore file to all the worker nodes and give the absolute path as below:

esSparkConf.put("es.net.ssl.truststore.location","file:///tmp/trust.jks")

Comment: Passing `--files` also "copies to all executor nodes". But you need to refer to the file using `file:/` URI, still. You can modify the classpath using [`spark.executor.extraClassPath` option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). Also note: You don't want to use `master("local")` when submitting to a cluster

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I modified this line master(""). I changed to line .set("spark.es.net.ssl.truststore.location","file://trust.jks")) . No luck. Still getting same error Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Expected to find keystore file at [file://trust.jks] but was unable to. Make sure that it is available on the classpath, or if not, that you have specified a valid URI.

Comment: I even tried by setting SparkSession .builder() .appName("ES dump job") .master("") .config(sparkConf) .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR") .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "trust.jks") .getOrCreate();

Comment: when we use --files ,where in the executor node this is downloaded?

Comment: It's non deterministic. That's what `SparkFiles.get` will return

Comment: @OneCricketeer I printed sparkfiles.get while running the program and checked in one of the worker node.but I couldn't find this folder it self. What could be the problem?

Comment: If you're using master("yarn"), or a Spark standalone cluster, the file path would refer to those machines, If you're deploying to k8s, then files end up in ephemeral containers, not directly on the hosts

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(fileName)` to get the actual path, and add the `file://` prefix.

```
sparkConf.set(
    "spark.es.net.ssl.truststore.location",
    "file://" + org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("trust.jks"))
```

See [SparkFiles.get](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html#get-java.lang.String-) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115914/apache-spark-sparkfiles-getfilename-txt-unable-to-retrieve-the-file-content).

Comment: it didn't work for me. This is not file I required for processing in executor(example csv, txt). It is truststore file which is needed for ES connection. sparkConf.set() is called at init(). So SparkFiles.get() is not available.

Comment: @Rakhs The executors are what actually connect to elasticsearch, so your file is needed in every executor

Comment: Did you try "file:///./trust.jks"?

Comment: @Dagang I tried. same error :-(

Comment: I am able to see this file under the 'staging' directory of GCS <bucket>/<>/jobs/<jobid>/staging

Comment: @Rakhs. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @VishalK no.. I had to copy the trustore file to all worker nodes..