# PySpark and Databricks addFile and SparkFiles.get Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to:

1. Load an SSL certification from S3 to a cluster.
2. `addFile` so all nodes see the file.
3. Create a connection URL to IBM db2 with JDBC.

Step 1 and Step 2 are working successfully. I can open the file with `with open(cert_filepath, "r") as file` and print it.

But in Step 3 I get the following error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.239.124.48 executor 1): com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.27.25] Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: Error opening socket to server / on port 53,101 with message: /local_disk0/spark-c30d1a7f-deea-4184-a9f9-2b6c9eab6c5e/userFiles-761620cf-2cb1-4623-9677-68694f0e4b3c/dwt01_db2_ssl.arm (No such file or directory). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

The port is `53101` but the error code puts a comma.

The essential part of code:

```py
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.download_file(
    Bucket="my-bucket-s3",
    Key="my/path/db2/dwt01_db2_ssl.arm",
    Filename="dwt01_db2_ssl.arm",
)
sc.addFile("dwt01_db2_ssl.arm")
cert_filepath = SparkFiles.get("dwt01_db2_ssl.arm")
user_name = cls.get_aws_secret(secret_name=cls._db2_username_aws_secret_name, key="username", region="eu-central-1")
password = cls.get_aws_secret(secret_name=cls._db2_password_aws_secret_name, key="password", region="eu-central-1")
driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:db2://{hostname}:{port}/{database}:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation={cert_filepath};"

df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", driver)
    .option("url", jdbc_url)
    .option("dbtable", f"({query}) as src")
    .option("user", user_name)
    .option("password", password)
    .load()
)
```

I can't seem to solve what could be the cause for this `FileNotFoundException` as it is there for at least when reading it and printing it.

Comment: refer this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115914/apache-spark-sparkfiles-
getfilename-txt-unable-to-retrieve-the-file-content

Comment: It did not help. What I have now concluded is that ```SparkFiles.get("file")``` only returns the master node path not the worker. Or code is executed in master node and then the db2 call is distributed to worker nodes, and path is still pointing to master node's path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException` because of the reason mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879478/sparkcontext-addfile-vs-spark-submit-files#comment65123346_38879788):

> In cluster mode, a local file, which has not been added to the spark-submit will not be found via addFile. This is because the driver (application master) is started on the cluster and is already running when he reaches the addFile call. It is too late at this point. The application has already been submitted, and the local file system is the file system of a specific cluster node.

So, to overcome this issue I'll suggest you use a DBFS path (eg: `/dbfs/dwt01_db2_ssl.arm`) for consistency and access across workers.

Here's your updated code:

```py
# sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.download_file(
    Bucket="my-bucket-s3",
    Key="my/path/db2/dwt01_db2_ssl.arm",
    Filename="dwt01_db2_ssl.arm",
)
# sc.addFile("dwt01_db2_ssl.arm")
# cert_filepath = SparkFiles.get("dwt01_db2_ssl.arm")
cert_filepath = "/dbfs/dwt01_db2_ssl.arm"
```

Afterward, you'll have to [configure spark SSL properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#ssl-configuration) as follows to continue because your code is missing this currently:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.ssl", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.ssl.trustStore", cert_filepath)
```

And then the rest of the code will be as follows:

```py
user_name = cls.get_aws_secret(secret_name=cls._db2_username_aws_secret_name, key="username", region="eu-central-1")
password = cls.get_aws_secret(secret_name=cls._db2_password_aws_secret_name, key="password", region="eu-central-1")
driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:db2://{hostname}:{port}/{database}:sslConnection=true;"

df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", driver)
    .option("url", jdbc_url)
    .option("dbtable", f"({query}) as src")
    .option("user", user_name)
    .option("password", password)
    .load()
)
```

**Note**: If you notice, I have removed `sslCertLocation` in `jdbc_url` because I don't think it's needed anymore as we have already configured spark SSL properties to handle that.

Now, doing the above changes should ideally resolve the error.

I suspect another issue might occur because of the `.arm` file as it's not a standard trust store format. But let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: I ended up doing just this, downloading first to dbfs and after use deleting the file. 
Only downside is that the rights to see what is inside dbfs in databricks UI is usually for all that can do work in the same workspace. The ssl cert is then revealed through dbsf